# Android ListView изменение цвета фона при заполнении

Tags: java, android, listview

Добрый день!
Есть `ListView` который заполняется данными из массива через `SimpleAdapter`. Возможно ли при заполнении в зависимости от параметров элемента заполнения - задавать цвет фона строки? Если да, то просьба показать как.
Спасибо!

Comment: Что за параметры заполнения, определенные значения в данных выделить цветом?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Сделал для Вас, такой пример:

1.list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llColors"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colors"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

2.MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Данные для ListView:
        String colors[] = {"Каждый", "Охотник", "Желает", "Знать", "Где", "Сидит", "Фазан"};

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
       CustomArrayAdapter listAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, colors);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

}
```

3.CustomArrayAdapter.java

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private String[] stringValues;

    public CustomArrayAdapter (Context context, String[] stringValues)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, stringValues);
        this.context = context;
        this.stringValues = stringValues;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.colors);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llColors);
        textView.setText(stringValues[position]);
        String s = stringValues[position];

        if (s.equals("Каждый"))
        {linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        }
        else if (s.equals("Охотник"))
        {linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
        }
        else if (s.equals("Желает"))
        {linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
        }
        else if (s.equals("Знать"))
        {linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
        }
        else if (s.equals("Где"))
        {linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_blue);
        }
        else if (s.equals("Сидит"))
        {linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        }
        else if (s.equals("Фазан"))
        {linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.purple);
        }
        else   linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        return view;
    }
}
```

4.colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="orange">#d24c09</color>
    <color name="yellow">#d2c509</color>
    <color name="green">#42d209</color>
    <color name="light_blue">#01c1f5</color>
    <color name="blue">#011df5</color>
    <color name="purple">#b001f5</color>
</resources>
```

Такой простенький и наглядный пример получился с `getView`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Отвлекся на другой момент, понял из первого ответа, что нужно писать кастомный адаптер. Захожу сюда, а тут замечательный пример!!!!

Comment: Замечательный пример!

Answer (score 2):

1. Напишите свой адаптер.
2. В методе `getView()` получайте корневой вью элемента.
3. Меняйте ему цвет.

Comment: Пожалуйста) Но у нас тут принято помимо спасибо ещё и за хорошие вопросы/ответы голосовать, если они полезными оказались)

Comment: У меня видать балов не хватает, я нажимаю кнопку вверх, а она сбрасывается.  Как наберу, обязательно вернусь и подниму)

Comment: Репы вам должно хватать...Видимо вы просто уже голосовали)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб подскажите как быть с динамическим изменением цвета текст вью? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529936/listview-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-textview