# Цветной ListView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать как сделать список(ListView) цветным. параметр android:background результатов не дает. Есть ли другие способы сделать список не белого цвета?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460982/191270

Answer (score 3):

Подставьте свою разметку в качестве разметки отдельного элемента списка. Именно в ней задавайте фон.