# Изменение фона ListView

Tags: android, listview, background

Как сделать чтобы изменялся фон элемента `ListView` в `ListActivity` в зависимости от текстового содержания этого элемента(данные приходят из MySql).

Кто какие варианты предложит?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460982/191270  посмотрите здесь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте свой адаптер и в зависимости от данных задавайте необходимый цвет фона для каждого элемента `ListView`.

Comment: можете подробней описать, рассказать, показать??

Answer (score 0):

Для Вашей цели проще создать своего посредника между адаптером и списком. Он в святых письменах называется биндер (Binder). Это мы вставляем в метод "Создать" Окно (Activity):

```
    // создааем адаптер
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view, null,
            new String[]{"name", "archive"}, new int[]{R.id.textView_task, R.id.LinearLayout_task}, 0);
    // указываем адаптеру свой биндер
    scAdapter.setViewBinder(new ArchiveViewBinder());
    // создааем список
    li = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.task_edit_listView);
    //настраиваем список (соединяем с адаптером)
    li.setAdapter(scAdapter);
```

Обратите внимание, в Адаптере стоит ссылка на курсор null по той причине, что я использую курсор-загрузчик, вошедший в душу класса окна:

```
public class Task_edit extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

В Вашем случае там может быть ссылка на Курсор.
Далее за фигурными скобками метода создания окна отдельным вложенным классом создаем биндер:

```
class ArchiveViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder
{
    int i;
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            // меняем фон линейной разметки в случае архивной задачи
            case R.id.LinearLayout_task:
                i = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                // если нужно поменять фон
                if (i == 1) view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_stop);
                // если нужно оставить фон по умолчанию
                else  view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_task);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Я меняю фон не надписи, а линейной разметки под надписью. По этому методу Вы можете менять основной фон и для любого элемента.
САМОЕ ВАЖНОЕ.
Обязательно переустанавливайте цвет фона для объектов, которым Вы меняете его, для КАЖДОГО пункта списка, даже если там не надо менять его (т.е. он должен остаться по умолчанию). Андроидный бог слишком ленив, чтобы создавать задний фон для каждого элемента списка, а берет его с ушедшего из зоны видимости пункта для вновь появившегося. Поэтому при листании списка туда-сюда, элементы закрашиваются помимо Вашей грешной воли.
Я привел Вам свой полностью рабочий код. Вам остается понять логику работы посредника (Биндера), который берет значения из указанных в Адаптере данных "фром", и кладет в "ту". Для полей, которые требуется изменить - Вы указываете Биндеру работу, а после его работы возвращаете через голубя мира "ретерн" "тру". А там, где не надо менять данные, шлете весточку "ложь", и тогда адаптер сам вставляет данные. То есть, заставляйте биндер исполнить только Вашу задачу изменения фона, а работу по умолчанию пусть выполняет сам Адаптер.