# listview динамическое изменение цвета textview

Tags: java, android, listview

ListView содержит 2 textView. 
Custom Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_row_online_entry,null);
        holder.tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_onlineentry1);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_onlineentry2);
        holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        //holder.tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        if ( holder.tv2.getText().equals("")){
            holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else {
            holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tv1.setText(myList.get(position).getOnlineEntryDate());
    holder.tv2.setText(myList.get(position).getOnlineEntryText());
    return convertView;
}
```

Сам листвью содержит 5 записей. Сейчас весь цвет загружается после построения вью. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы цвет текста в текствью менялся динамически после внесения изменения в текст вью? Правильно ли это делать в адаптере? или нужно вносить изменения в активити?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принцип такой:

1. В getView адаптера сначала формируем холдер
2. Только потом, с уже имеющимся холдером, меняем свойства элементов разметки

В этом случае, если мы поменяем что-то в данных адаптера, от коих зависит разметка то, после вызова `notifyDataSetChanged()` адаптер перерисует элементы согласно новым условиям.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_row_online_entry,null);
        //только находим элементы в разметке, но не меняем их
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    //тут назначаем свойства разметке в зависимости от данных 
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: То, что надо! Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если в ListView будет 5 записей, то стоит ли его использовать вообще т.к. все записи будут постоянно на экране. может стоит пересмотреть компоновку? Тогда программно в активити внесете изменение цвета кнопок. Адаптер же служит все таки для согласования данных между источником и отображением. Само отображение, компоновку, цветовое оформление целесообразнее возложить на активити.

Comment: через активити не нашел, как можно менять данные текст вью в адаптере.