# Выбор элемента listview

Tags: android, listview

Необходимо заменить цвет бэкграунда у выбранного элемента lisview. Цвет меняю так:

```
listpos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    listpos.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Цвет меняется, однако у нескольких элементов. Например, если выбран первый элемент, то меняется цвет у него и у следующего элемента, который следует за последним отображаемым на экране. Как будто position отсчитывается от нуля, а дальше, как закончился экран и необходимо прокрутить, обнуляется

Comment: Если вы используете ListView, а не RecyclerView и у вас возникает такая проблема, то скорее всего вы реализовали паттерн ViewHolder. Он переиспользует ранее созданый холдер для итемов. т.е. холедр с красным фоном будет переиспользован как только о нперестаёт быть видимым, а на экране надо отобразить новый элемент

Comment: @SviatVolkov а можно поподробнее, что я должен сделал для корректного отображения выделенного элемента

Comment: @SviatVolkov  паттерн ViewHolder - просто кэширование ссылки на виджеты и ничего общего с механизмом переиспользования айтемов не имеет, не надо вводить людей в заблуждение. Однако сами виджеты (и ListView и RecyclerView) действительно многократно переиспользуют созданные ранее айтемы и для решения проблемы в вопросе нужно писать кастомный адаптер, который будет запоминать, для какого айтема какой цвет установлен. Этой проблеме уже посвещенно множество прекрасных ответов на данном ресурсе и тут даже есть поиск ..

Comment: cv смотрите, например,  [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460982/177345)